# How to create file in Visual c++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I try create file in visual studio c++.

But it now work, what is wrong?

```
CreateFile("1",            
                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                   0,                    
                   NULL,                 
                   OPEN_EXISTING,        
                   FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
                   NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create a file (not open it), you should not specify the OPEN_EXISTING flag. Instead, pass the CREATE_NEW constant:

```
CreateFile("1",            
                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                   0,                    
                   NULL,                 
                   CREATE_NEW,        
                   FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
                   NULL);
```

Comment: #include <windows.h> at the top of your CPP file. First you should learn how to program, then start messing with WinAPI.

Answer (score 0):

This code tries to open existing file: OPEN_EXISTING. Replace it with CREATE_NEW to create new file.